# XML Attributes of C# Class - attribute and value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize a C# class into the following:

```
<ns3:Test ab="11111">Test 123</ns3:Test>
```

My class looks like this:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://foo")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ab")]
    public string Ab { get; set; } = "11111";

    [XmlElement("Test")]
    public string Test1 { get; set; } = "Test 123";
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
  <ns3:Test tc="11111">
    <ns3:Test>Test 123</ns3:Test>
  </ns3:Test>
```

My class definition is obviously wrong.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for using annotations?

Comment: What you posted is impossible.  Recompile your code and try again.  In the project bin folder there is a debug and release folder.  Make sure you are running the correct version by recompiling and checking the timestamp of the exe file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the attribute of `Test1` with this:

```
[XmlText]
public string Test1 { get; set; } = "Test 123";
```

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I was missing!